# Find workspace and delete everything with the name, except for filename and everything in a directory pattern

Tags: linux, find

I'm trying to create a cronjob that will delete everything with a pattern *.jar, except for master.jar and anything in a directory pattern */jarkeeper/*/staging/*

I'm close but not luck in finding the correct command. Here's what i have so far:

```
find /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ ! -path "*/jarkeeper/*/staging/*" -or -type f ! -name master.jar -name \*.jar
```

and

```
find /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ \( ! -path "*/jarkeeper/*/staging/*" \) -or \( -type f ! -name master.jar \) -name \*.jar
```

What should the correct format be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue looks like you are using -or as opposed to -or. I would also suggest using -path as opposed to -name throughout to keep everything consistent and so:

```
find /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ -type f ! -path "*master.jar" -or ! -path "*/jarkeeper/*/staging/*" -or -path "*.jar"
```

Comment: This worked for me! -or ! -path "*/jarkeeper/*/staging/*"  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As an idea, I've always felt more comfortable combining more primitive tools than to use find's complex syntax, like:

```
find $somewhere -name \*.jar | grep -v master.jar | \
    grep -vE "jarkeeper/.*/staging/" | xargs rm -rf
```

This also comes at the advantage that you can test/check/debug your scripts part by part.